# My Azure Web App redirecting to another URL even though no re-write rules in Web.Config

Tags: azure-web-app-service

When I browse to my Azure webapp URL, I am re-directed to some other URL. I don't have any re-write rules in my web.config file. How can I analyze what is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you give specifics? What's the URL? How did you set it up? What does it redirect to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an asp site that was having similar re-direct issue with status code 302.
Below are the steps, that I followed to analyze the problem. I’ve enabled Freb logs on Azure and have documented the steps below.

**Step 1: Update your Web Config**

Enabling Failed Request Tracing will help identify where in the request pipeline the request is hanging.
To enable Failed Request Tracing on you Azure App Service, add the following code snippet to the wwwroot web.config of your App Service.  Add it within the  section.

```
<tracing>
<traceFailedRequests>
<remove path="*" />
<add path="*">
<traceAreas>
<add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
<add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
<add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
<add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,
Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI"
verbosity="Verbose" />
</traceAreas>
<failureDefinitions statusCodes="300-399" />
</add>
</traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
```

NOTE: Here, If the request HTTP status is between 300 and 399, the request gets logged. You can log requests based on your error code.

**Step 2 : Enable Failed Request Tracing from Azure Portal**

Open Azure Portal and go to your App Service page. Enable Failed Request Tracing in the diagnostics logs section as shown in the figure below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQbAk.png

**Step 3 : Repro the Issue**

Now, browse to the URL that is causing this issue and reproduce the issue and you should now have the FREB log file created .

**Step 4 : Analyze the Logs**

Browse to https://yourAppService.scm.azurewebsites.net and then select Debug Console on the tool bar as below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfs7u.jpg

Now, few options would be displayed, you need to select LogFiles folder and then look for W3SVC*****  folder as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ea9k.jpg

That’s where you see Freb log files in fr*****.xml format. You will notice an option to download the file as highlighted below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPDxY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iusxc.jpg

In my repro, I had seen from the logs that my asp application was throwing 302 error and has a response redirect in my code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1sno.png

Hope this works for you.